# How to keep background image switching even after i perform functions like Submit or Reset on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have recently added a JavaScript function to my page that switches the background image of my page at intervals of 5 seconds. There is an input form in that page as well, and when I click the Submit button, the switching stops and goes back to the first image, and the switching starts all over again.

How do I keep the background image continuously switching regardless of what I do in that page?

I think I can fix this with localStorage property, but I am not sure how to implement that in this particular code, any ideas?

```
<body class="main">
       <div class ="up">
           <img src='images/usa.jpg' id="circle"/>
        </div>

<script>
var image_tracker = 'usa';
function change(){

    var image = document.getElementById('circle');
    if(image_tracker=='usa'){

        image.src = 'images/O_Square_P1.jpg';
        image_tracker = 'uthant';
    }
    else if(image_tracker=='uthant'){

        image.src = 'images/U_Thant_PIC_3.jpg';
        image_tracker = 'oasis';
    }

    else if(image_tracker=='oasis'){

        image.src = 'images/usa.jpg';
        image_tracker= 'usa';
    }
}

var timer = setInterval('change();',5000);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While submitting via ajax is a good idea, this is how to do it via `localStorage`.

```
<body class="main">

<div class="up">
    <img src='images/loading.gif' id="circle"/>
</div>
<script>
    var image_tracker = localStorage.image_tracker || 'oasis';

    function change(){

        var image = document.getElementById('circle');
        if(image_tracker=='usa'){
            image.src = 'images/O_Square_P1.jpg';
            image_tracker = 'uthant';
        }

        else if(image_tracker=='uthant'){
            image.src = 'images/U_Thant_PIC_3.jpg';
            image_tracker = 'oasis';
        }

        else if(image_tracker=='oasis'){
            image.src = 'images/usa.jpg';
            image_tracker= 'usa';
        }

        localStorage.setItem("image_tracker", image_tracker);//Sets image tracker to localstorage
    }
    change();//runs on refresh to ensure loop continues from last image
    var timer = setInterval('change();',5000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It did work, but now when the Submit button is clicked, the background image changes to the next image as well, how to make the Submit button(button refreshes the page) to not interfere with the background image switching?

Comment: Move `localStorage.setItem("image_tracker", image_tracker)` up to before the `if` statements. That way, when the page refreshes, it will be the same image. Or u can submit the form using Ajax.

Comment: U have helped me so much @Overcomer, you are absolutely spot on with your statements, now the background can run some sort how I imagined thank you again =)

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your form is being submitted / validated.

You could perform the submit / validation via AJAX. Then you could prevent the default beaviour of your submit event.